# Mac Word 2016 - Change Templates folder location programatically

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, office-2016

In Mac Word 2011, User Templates are stored here by default:
~\Library\Application Support\Microsoft\Office\User Templates\My Templates

In Mac Word 2016, they appear to be stored here:
~\Library\Group Containers\UBF8T346G9.Office\User Content\Templates

I know I can manually change folder locations in the Word Preferences. Is there any way to change this location programmatically, either using VBA, Applescript, or the command line?

The path change breaks existing solutions, so I'd like to be able to distribute a shell script or macro to users to automatically change the path back to the 2011 location.